# Highlight listview header when mouse hover over it

Tags: c++, api

I am trying to highlight owner draw listview header when mouse hover over it. I sub-classed the header control.
I am trying to capture WM_MOUSEMOVE message in the header control window procedure. But the message does not get sent to the header.
What should I do?

Comment: You're going to need to show what you've done.  It sounds like there is either a mouse capture on another window, or the subclassing has not been done correctly.

Comment: Impossible to troubleshoot without code